# How to stop magento from setting Payment-Status to "Completed" when Payment comes in via PayPal

Tags: magento, paypal, status

Is there a way to stop magento setting the status of an order to "completed" after the payment comes in via PayPal?
The Problem is that I want do send an invoice when I start with the service, which is not possible when someone pays it before.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem right, try next:

In Magento PayPal settings, find field "Payment Action", and set it to "Authorization"

This mean:

> payments are only authorized at the side of the PayPal system and only
>   an order is created in the backend of your store. The store
>   administrator needs log to on to the merchant account on the PayPal
>   site and capture the transaction.

So after order placed and user have paid transaction, status in your shop will stay at "Pending" or "Processing". After that you can generate invoice and send it to customer, and then go to your PayPal and finalize order.

Source here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-paypal-for-your-magento-store/

Comment: Maybe that would be good if I dont't have to log into PayPal every time and accept the payment. Isn't there a magento-side solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, as I know, with default Magento functionality no way to do this.